# Token indices sequence length Issue

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I am running a sentence transformer model and trying to truncate my tokens, but it doesn't appear to be working. My code is

```
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
model_name = "sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2"
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    
text_tokens = tokenizer(text, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
text_embedding = model(**text_tokens)["pooler_output"]
```

I keep getting the following warning:

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length 
for this model (909 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in 
indexing errors
```

I am wondering why setting `truncation=True` is not truncating my text to the desired length?

Comment: Which version of transformers are you using? Please give the output of `transformers-cli env`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `max_length` parameter while creating the tokenizer like below:

`text_tokens = tokenizer(text, padding=True, max_length=512, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")`

### Reason:

`truncation=True` without `max_length` parameter takes sequence length equal to maximum acceptable input length by the model.

It is `1e30` or `1000000000000000019884624838656` for this model. You can check by printing out `tokenizer.model_max_length`.

According to the Huggingface documentation about `truncation`,

> True or 'only_first' truncate to a maximum length specified by the
> max_length argument or the maximum length accepted by the model if no
> max_length is provided (max_length=None).